# JAXB unmarshalling a 2.7gb xml file

Tags: java, memory, jaxb

I have an Adobe Premiere Pro project file that I've unzipped so it is now an xml file detailing my film edit project.

The file is now 2.7gb...

I created an XSD schema from the xml file with Intellij's function for this, then again, using Intellij's JAXB tools, generated a package full of classes representing the xml hierarchy, from the .xsd.

My code for unmarshalling is as follows:

```
import mypackage.PremiereDataType;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    // write your code here

        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("mypackage");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<PremiereDataType> premiereDataJAXB
                = (JAXBElement<PremiereDataType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(
                new File("20200108_WLM_MW_v706_JGal_review_R2_markers_CONSOLIDATE.xml"));
        System.out.println(premiereDataJAXB);

    }
}
```

My machine has 32gb of Ram.
I'm not up to scratch on how to fine tune memory usage in Intellij but I suspect I'm running out of memory?

After fifteen minutes or so the program crashes with a EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000713e4f85, pid=27780, tid=0x000000000000394c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_251-b08) (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.251-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x104f85]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\malcolm\IdeaProjects\pprojConsolidator\hs_err_pid27780.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The log file for the crash is below (truncated so this question doesn't violate the character limit).
Would the lines indicating "object space" had reached "99% used" be an indication of the problem?
Can I increase a limit somewhere so there is more object space?

Any help getting a handle on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000713e4f85, pid=27780, tid=0x000000000000394c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_251-b08) (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.251-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x104f85]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002eec800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000015020000,0x0000000015120000] [id=14668]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x000000001d4b0000, RBX=0x0000000071b0af90, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x1fffffffe2399d81
RSP=0x000000001511f820, RBP=0x00000000292d0eb0, RSI=0xffffffffda000000, RDI=0x0000000000000001
R8 =0x007fffffff88e676, R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff, R10=0x00000000000024f7, R11=0x0912412248244900
R12=0x00000006138cec10, R13=0x000000000000000a, R14=0x00000006138cebd8, R15=0x000000000000000a
RIP=0x00000000713e4f85, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001511f820)
0x000000001511f820:   00000005c35048e8 0000000000000003
0x000000001511f830:   00000005c35048f0 00000000713f5269
0x000000001511f840:   00000006038cec10 00000000716dc62b
0x000000001511f850:   0000000071b0af90 ffffffffda000000
0x000000001511f860:   00000000292d0eb0 000000007141b6f3
0x000000001511f870:   ffffffffda000000 00000000713ed2fc
0x000000001511f880:   00000006038cec10 00000006138cebec
0x000000001511f890:   00000006138cebe8 0000000000000004
0x000000001511f8a0:   00000006038cec10 000000007141b5ea
0x000000001511f8b0:   15c5cf35000024f7 00000000713f54a6
0x000000001511f8c0:   00000006138cebd8 00000006138cebd4
0x000000001511f8d0:   00000000292d0eb0 000000007141b6f3
0x000000001511f8e0:   0000000000000000 0000000002ee9d00
0x000000001511f8f0:   0000000002eceb90 0000000000000000
0x000000001511f900:   15c5cf35000024f7 00000000716dff80
0x000000001511f910:   00000000292d0eb0 15c5cf36000024f7 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000713e4f85)
0x00000000713e4f65:   48 89 74 24 10 57 48 83 ec 20 48 8b 41 20 4c 8b
0x00000000713e4f75:   c2 0f b6 ca 49 c1 e8 06 80 e1 3f bf 01 00 00 00
0x00000000713e4f85:   4a 8b 1c c0 4a 8d 34 c0 48 d3 e7 48 8b c3 48 0b
0x00000000713e4f95:   c7 48 3b c3 74 27 0f 1f 44 00 00 4c 8b c3 48 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000001d4b0000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000071b0af90 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x1fffffffe2399d81 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001511f820 is an unknown value
RBP=0x00000000292d0eb0 is an unknown value
RSI=0xffffffffda000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R8 =0x007fffffff88e676 is an unknown value
R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000000024f7 is an unknown value
R11=0x0912412248244900 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000006138cec10 is an oop
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement 
 - klass: 'javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement'
R13=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
R14=0x00000006138cebd8 is an oop
[Ljava.lang.Object; 
 - klass: 'java/lang/Object'[]
 - length: 10
R15=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000015020000,0x0000000015120000],  sp=0x000000001511f820,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x104f85]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fc62b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x10d2fc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13b5ea]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fff80]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fd8ff]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fad6e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2a001a]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17bd4]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6ce51]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

[..]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000026ec6000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000002bfb0000,0x000000002c0b0000] [id=25136]
  0x00000000295dc800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000002d7b0000,0x000000002d8b0000] [id=29304]

=>0x0000000002eec800 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000015020000,0x0000000015120000] [id=14668]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000002eb0d50] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000026ec6000
[0x0000000002eb0b50] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000002eb3800

heap address: 0x00000005c1c00000, size: 8164 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012370000,0x0000000013370000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000f562000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000071b0af90
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000015520000, 0x000000001d4b0000)
 End Bits:   [0x000000001d4b0000, 0x0000000025440000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000e50000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=12460Kb max_used=12807Kb free=233299Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002fb0000, 0x0000000003c50000, 0x0000000011fb0000]
 total_blobs=3495 nmethods=3202 adapters=201
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1014.137 Thread 0x00000000294db800 3322       4       java.lang.reflect.Constructor::newInstance (87 bytes)
Event: 1014.137 Thread 0x000000002953e000 3323 % !   4       com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader::startElement @ 136 (433 bytes)
Event: 1014.137 Thread 0x0000000029541000 3324       4       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl::newInstance (9 bytes)
Event: 1014.138 Thread 0x0000000029541000 nmethod 3324 0x0000000003b6c990 code [0x0000000003b6cac0, 0x0000000003b6cb58]
Event: 1014.138 Thread 0x000000002953f800 3325   !   3       sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor152::newInstance (49 bytes)
Event: 1014.138 Thread 0x00000000294d5800 3326   !   4       com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl::createInstance (91 bytes)
Event: 1020.495 Thread 0x000000002953f800 nmethod 3325 0x000000000331e7d0 code [0x000000000331e9a0, 0x000000000331f018]
Event: 1026.864 Thread 0x00000000294db800 nmethod 3322 0x000000000339b3d0 code [0x000000000339b560, 0x000000000339b870]
Event: 1026.864 Thread 0x000000002953c000 3327   !   3       sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor153::newInstance (49 bytes)
Event: 1033.175 Thread 0x000000002953c000 nmethod 3327 0x000000000331d2d0 code [0x000000000331d480, 0x000000000331d928]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 1064.811 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=180 (full 161):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750591K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 99% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743bffc70,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1064.811 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=181 (full 162):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1071.135 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=181 (full 162):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750591K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 99% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743bffe50,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1071.135 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=182 (full 163):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1077.405 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=182 (full 163):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750591K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 99% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743bfff28,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1077.406 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=183 (full 164):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1083.711 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=183 (full 164):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750591K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 99% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743bfff90,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1083.711 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=184 (full 165):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1090.012 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=184 (full 165):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750591K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 99% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743bfffc8,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1090.013 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=185 (full 166):
 PSYoungGen      total 1679360K, used 750592K [0x0000000715f00000, 0x00000007ba300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 750592K, 100% used [0x0000000715f00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000)
  from space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000743c00000,0x0000000743c00000,0x000000077c700000)
  to   space 928768K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x00000007ba300000)
 ParOldGen       total 5573632K, used 5573217K [0x00000005c1c00000, 0x0000000715f00000, 0x0000000715f00000)
  object space 5573632K, 99% used [0x00000005c1c00000,0x0000000715e98680,0x0000000715f00000)
 Metaspace       used 14801K, capacity 14959K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1695K, capacity 1741K, committed 1920K, reserved 1048576K

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 1.946 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003927838 method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$State.<init>(Lcom/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallingContext;Lcom/sun/xml/inte
Event: 1.946 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003945470 method=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SymbolTable.addSymbol([CII)Ljava/lang/String; @ 64
Event: 1.947 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000039038e8 method=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SymbolTable.addSymbol([CII)Ljava/lang/String; @ 64
Event: 2.090 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003922ef4 method=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read([CII)I @ 131
Event: 2.131 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003ac741c method=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next()I @ 1171
Event: 2.496 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003b44128 method=java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1([BII)I @ 22
Event: 2.497 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003a847e8 method=java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1([BII)I @ 22
Event: 2.801 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x00000000039ba58c method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 31
Event: 2.802 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000003984854 method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 31
Event: 2.802 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x000000000397c384 method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 31

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.407 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000007186c7798) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u251\737\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 0.423 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 42> (0x00000007187e0ad8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u251\737\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 368]
Event: 0.461 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException': sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class> (0x00000007194c3120) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u251\737\hotspot\src\share\vm\i
Event: 1.028 Thread 0x0000000029452800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000034196fd to 0x0000000003419b59
Event: 1.562 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000360b3e1 to 0x000000000360b711
Event: 1.562 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000037f0c52 to 0x00000000037f2085
Event: 1.639 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000033a305e to 0x00000000033a3219
Event: 2.801 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000039b7f51 to 0x00000000039ba551
Event: 2.802 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000039839be to 0x0000000003984831
Event: 2.802 Thread 0x0000000002eb3800 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000397b78e to 0x000000000397c379

Events (10 events):
Event: 1064.811 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 1064.811 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 1071.135 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 1071.135 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 1077.405 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 1077.405 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 1083.711 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 1083.711 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 1090.012 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 1090.012 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff764880000 - 0x00007ff7648b7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffb76aa0000 - 0x00007ffb76c90000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffb12250000 - 0x00007ffb12263000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswhook.dll
0x00007ffb75370000 - 0x00007ffb75422000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffb74820000 - 0x00007ffb74ac4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffb75d20000 - 0x00007ffb75dc3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffb767b0000 - 0x00007ffb7684e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffb766d0000 - 0x00007ffb76767000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffb755f0000 - 0x00007ffb75710000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffb76850000 - 0x00007ffb769e4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffb746a0000 - 0x00007ffb746c1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffb76780000 - 0x00007ffb767a6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffb741d0000 - 0x00007ffb74364000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffb745b0000 - 0x00007ffb7464e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffb744b0000 - 0x00007ffb745aa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffb69610000 - 0x00007ffb69894000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.836_none_e6c4b943130f18ed\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffb75dd0000 - 0x00007ffb76106000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffb74ad0000 - 0x00007ffb74b50000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffb75710000 - 0x00007ffb7573e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000071b90000 - 0x0000000071c62000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000712e0000 - 0x0000000071b8b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffb76770000 - 0x00007ffb76778000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffb63260000 - 0x00007ffb63269000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffb769f0000 - 0x00007ffb76a5f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffb704a0000 - 0x00007ffb704c4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffb6cc90000 - 0x00007ffb6cc9a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffb70470000 - 0x00007ffb7049d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffb74650000 - 0x00007ffb7469a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffb6ac90000 - 0x00007ffb6ac9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ffb686d0000 - 0x00007ffb686f9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ffb684e0000 - 0x00007ffb68503000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x00007ffb686b0000 - 0x00007ffb686c6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffb74c70000 - 0x00007ffb75354000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffb75980000 - 0x00007ffb75a29000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffb73a30000 - 0x00007ffb741ae000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffb73a00000 - 0x00007ffb73a23000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffb73970000 - 0x00007ffb739ba000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffb73960000 - 0x00007ffb73970000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\UMPDC.dll
0x00007ffb74b50000 - 0x00007ffb74ba2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffb739e0000 - 0x00007ffb739f1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffb741b0000 - 0x00007ffb741c7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cryptsp.dll
0x00007ffb67c40000 - 0x00007ffb67c5a000     C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00007ffb435e0000 - 0x00007ffb435fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffb731d0000 - 0x00007ffb73237000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffb6bb20000 - 0x00007ffb6bd14000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=61834:C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.qhf.Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\malcolm\IdeaProjects\pprojConsolidator\out\production\pprojConsolidator;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;;C:\Program Files (x86)\HighPoint Technologies, Inc\HighPoint RocketStor Manager\Service;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\Sequencer\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\FFmpeg\bin;;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\malcolm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\bin;
USERNAME=malcolm
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 1 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a large file. Set VM startup settings -Xms and -Xmx large as possible.

It is a crash rather than OutOfMemoryException so it might be worth trying JDK9+. Then also the String tables are smaller (if you have latin chars) and that might also give  better chance of unmarshalling the XML. If you are stuck, using XML SAX handlers may allow you to extract it in sub-sections but with a lot more coding effort.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Java 13 and jumped through the hoops to get JAXB working with that release.
No more EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION!